# Yahoo forex dates are off?

Tags: python, yahoo, datareader, forex

There is something fishy with either the DataReader or the Yahoo data themselves:

```
start = datetime.datetime(2012,9,27)
end   = datetime.datetime(2013,12,31)
n = 'GBPUSD=X'
us = web.DataReader(n, 'yahoo', start, end)
us.Close

Date
2012-09-25    1.619433
2012-09-26    1.617861
2012-09-27    1.623298
2012-09-30    1.612487
2012-10-01    1.612903
2012-10-02    1.613163
2012-10-03    1.610047
2012-10-04    1.618647
2012-10-07    1.613892
2012-10-08    1.603412
2012-10-09    1.599693
....
```

(Where is Friday 2012-09-28?)

(Where is Friday 2012-10-05?)

It seems the data are off. They include Sundays but exclude Fridays??
Also, I'm asking for September 27th, but get September 25th as the first date?

What's going on?
Anyone have any clues?

(It seems the weekdays are back in sync after a few weeks. How can I align the weeks that are off?)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the weeks are just randomly off, and there is indeed something wrong with the data from Yahoo.

This is how to generate a new data frame with the correct data and dates:

```
#generate a new range of dates
dates = p.bdate_range(p.to_datetime('2012-01-01', format='%Y-%m-%d'), periods=330)
#get the column names from the old data frame
colnames = db.columns.get_values()
coln = colnames.tolist()
#generate a new data frame with values and column names from the old data frame (db), the new dates (dates)
newdb = p.DataFrame(db.values, dates, columns=coln).set_index(dates)
```